# Xarmin iOS MSBuild - Missing OutputPath?

Tags: ios, xamarin, msbuild

I am currently building my Xamarmin iOS project from the command line:

```
MSBuild "C:\code\MyProject.iOS.csproj" /t:Build /p:Configuration=Ad-Hoc;Platform=iPhone;ServerAddress=MACIP;ServerUser=MACUSER
```

It fails with the following error:

> The OutputPath property is not set for project 'MyProject.iOS.csproj'.
>   Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination
>   of Configuration and Platform for this project.

However, I there is an OutputPath set when I examine the CSPROJ.

[image]

I can get around this by forcing an "OutputPath" parameter at the command line:

```
OutputPath="C:\builds\xamarin\cellar-ios"
```

**Note:** `OutputPath="C:\builds\xamarin\cellar-ios\"` does not work and build fails (notice ending back slash)

However this creates a strange folder structure where it appends the filename:

[image]

Thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here? I feel the setup is very close!

**EDIT**

Using the following parameters I'm able to get it to work. Note I still have to manually include the `OutputPath` but this gets me by for now.

```
/t:Build /p:Configuration=Ad-Hoc;Platform=iPhone;ServerAddress=SERVER_IP;ServerUser=USER;ServerPassword=PASS;OutputPath=bin\iPhone\Ad-Hoc\
```

Comment: I believe the `OutputPath` relates to the Windows cache of the build. I can't seem to replicate this issue locally however. It seems to be correct with regards to the `OutputPath` within the `.csproj`. (Even changing this yields the same results).

Comment: Hey Jon, thx for the response. So when you run MSBuild without the OutputPath where does it generate the IPA? Just the \bin\iPhone (as I have it) directory? Strange I'm receiving that error what I'm doing should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: It'll default to the default `OutputPath` AFAIK. On the Mac in the `Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds`

Comment: I meant on Windows where does the IPA output too (in your case)?

Comment: It'll be inside the respective `OutputPath/{AppName TimeStamp}`

Comment: So running my exact command without an OutputPath works? What version of MSBuild are you attempting with? Just trying to eliminate variables at this point: Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1

Comment: Yes that's correct. I'm running 14.0.25420.1

Comment: @JonDouglas digging in further looks like it's failing when trying to build the PCL project that is associated with the iOS project in my Forms Solution. Anyway around this?http://imgur.com/a/II8ty

Comment: Can you upload a sample and edit your question?

Answer (score 3):

For any customized `OutputPath` of your .csproj, it should be picked up by `xbuild/msbuild` within the `.csproj` or provided as a property.

One thing you can do to customize the output path of the IPA would be to use a custom MSBuild target to copy the IPA to a folder of your choice(You could use a move task if you needed):

i.e. (Inside your `.csproj`):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CreateIpaDependsOn>
        $(CreateIpaDependsOn);
        CopyIpa
    </CreateIpaDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="CopyIpa"
    Condition="'$(OutputType)' == 'Exe'
        And '$(ComputedPlatform)' == 'iPhone'
        And '$(BuildIpa)' == 'true'">
    <Copy
        SourceFiles="$(IpaPackagePath)"
        DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)"
    />
</Target>
```

You then set the `DestinationFolder` to the desired output folder.

This is found in our KB articles here: https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/2061038-can-i-change-the-output-path-of-the-ipa-file-

Comment: Thanks for all your help Jon. I've updated my CSProj to include this, however I'm still receiving the OutputPath folder error. It's forcing me to include that parameter in the Build command...http://i.imgur.com/O5TS8Vb.png